# Why NSNumber comparison method different?

Tags: objective-c

I used NSNumber class.

but methods that can use is different in follow environments.

First is a picture in command line tool environment. (Mac os x)

Second is a picture in single view application environment. (iOS)

: Can't use isGreaterThan:, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:, isLessThan:.. Etc. methods

Why did that?

> 1] first picture

[image: first picture]

> 2] second picture

[image: second picture]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those methods you're seeing on the Mac aren't actually part of the `NSNumber` class but instead are part of an informal protocol called [`NSComparisonMethods`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) that is only available on Mac OS X. The methods in this protocol are convenience methods that actually just use the `compare:` method already available on many Cocoa classes. If you wanted, you could implement these methods as a category on `NSNumber` quite easily. Here is how I would implement `-isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:`.

```
@interface NSNumber (ConvenientComparison)

- (BOOL)isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:(id)object;

@end

@implementation NSNumber (ConvenientComparison)

- (BOOL)isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:(id)object
{
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        // Not sure what NSNumber does if you pass in something that isn't a number.
        // Handle this case
        return NO;
    }

    NSNumber *numberToCompareAgainst = (NSNumber *)object;

    NSComparisonResult comparisonResult = [self compare:numberToCompareAgainst];

    if (comparisonResult == NSOrderedSame || comparisonResult == NSOrdereedDescending)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are part of the NSComparisonMethods protocol, which exists on the Mac but not on iOS. As for why it doesn't exist on iOS: It's part of Cocoa's scripting support, which did not get ported to iOS since AppleScript and OSA don't exist there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of why there is a difference.  I checked the documentation for ios 5.0 and OS X 10.6.  They both don't have the isGreater... methods.

You can compare your `NSNumber`s using

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSNumber *)aNumber

NSComparisonResult compResult = [test compare:aNumber];
```

and check for test >= aNumber

```
if (compResult == NSOrderedDescending || compResult == NSOrderedSame) {

}
```

> Return Value NSOrderedAscending if the value of aNumber is greater
>   than the receiver’s, NSOrderedSame if they’re equal, and
>   NSOrderedDescending if the value of aNumber is less than the
>   receiver’s.

Comment: Why on earth would you use a BOOL here?